# with-open-file macro in C

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to write a **C** macro which would take some action before and another action after a code block?

```
int is_locked;
#define LOCKED for(is_locked = 1, lock_something(); is_locked; is_locked = 0, unlock_something())

LOCKED{
    ...
    do_something_under_lock();
    ...
}
```

This would work; however, it requires the variable `is_locked` to check if we are in lock. Is there another possible solution?

Comment: Why don't you just write a *function?*

Comment: @H2CO3 how would you write this using a function?

Comment: If C++ is an option, RAII is the way to do this.  If not, IMO you're better off simply maintaining `is_locked`, things like macro hacks are likely more trouble than they're worth.  (It might help to think of the lock acquisition the same way you'd treat use of `free()` etc. - in this way it's just like RAII but with more manual steps.)

Comment: @unwind please explain what do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted almost works. With a minor modification, this compiles with a C99 compiler:

```
#define LOCKED for(int lockvar = (lock_something(), 1);       \
                   lockvar; \
                   lockvar = 0, unlock_something())
```

However, unlike a C++ guard class, it is very error-prone because `unlock_something()` will *not* trigger if the block is exited with `return`, `goto`, or `break`. In addition to that, `break` will have a completely different meaning:

```
for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  LOCKED {
    if (condition)
      break;  // exits the LOCKED block, not the loop -- WITHOUT unlocking
    if (other_condition)
      return; // returns from function, but never unlocks
  }
}
```

This approach is not recommended in production code.

Comment: You can catch the `break` by using *two* `for` loops and having the unlock be in the outer one. Then you just have to document that `LOCKED` is `break`able.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef void(*vrv)(void);

void before_after(vrv before, vrv func, vrv after) {
  before();
  func();
  after();
}

void b() { printf(" 1 "); }
void a() { printf(" 3 "); }
void f() { printf(" 2 "); }

int main() {
  before_after(b, f, a); 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you need to write function instead of just using block of code? Isn't it more verbose than just writing plain code with "b(); f(); a();"?

Comment: @JohnRivers, what is your question then? This thing is not fixed to certain before, after functions.

Comment: @H2CO3 it would be much more verbose if you need to use some local variables - you should make it function args in this case.

Comment: @perreal in your example, I want `printf(" 2 ")` to be defined in main() body, not in dedicated function.